# express error - cannot find module - static file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, static-files

I keep getting an error that says it cannot find the module reddit.js. I have a folder called "routes" (without quotes) in my directory. In that folder I have reddit.js which is middleware. On the first file below, I did change it to var reddit = require('./routes/reddit.js') and I received the error messsage that says "throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a
            ^
TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use "

When I keep the code as shown below I get this error:

Error: Cannot find module 'reddit.js'

---

my app.js file contains the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var reddit = require('reddit.js');

app.use ('/', reddit);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('public/js'));
app.use(express.static('public/images'));
app.use(express.static('routes'));
```

my reddit.js file contains the following code:

```
var express = require ('express');
var request = require ('request');
var reddit = express.Router();

reddit.get(function (req, res, next) {
    request('https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/hot.json',function(error, response, body){
        console.log(body);
        var docs = JSON.parse(body).response;
        //var titles = [];
        console.log(docs);
        res.send(docs);
        next;
    });
});
```

---

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `reddit.js` is in the same directory as `app.js`, then you need to use `require('./reddit.js');`.  Node.js does not automatically look in the current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentioned below are the list of things that are not correct

- You don't need to have `.js` extensions for including files. Use  `require('/path/to/reddit');` instead of `require('reddit.js');`
- You need to export the router instance in `reddit.js`. Add `module.exports = reddit;` at the end of the file.
- Don't call `next()` after sending out the response using `res.send(docs);`
- Routes are not static content. Remove `app.use(express.static('routes'));`
- `app.use(express.static('/public'));` handles all static content inside the `/public` folder. You do not need to add `app.use(express.static('/public/js'));`